# how to covert dynamic linking to static linking

Tags: c, linux, static-linking, dynamic-linking, libevent

I have a program which use libevent library

when compile the program, the compiling command is like:

```
 gcc -o myprogram mysource.c mysource.h -levent
```

so it is dynamic linking.

now I want to run this program on a computer where there is no libevent,
I need static linking so that my program can be run on that computer,
are there any easy steps?

I tried `-static`, but I got the following error:

```
    [root@kitty relay]# gcc  -o relay -static mysource.c mysource.h -levent -lpcap
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `libevent.a`. Then you can just `gcc -o myprogram mysource.c libevent.a`.

Or try `gcc -o myprogram -static mysource.c -levent`.

(And you probably shouldn't specify `mysource.h` to gcc as it's most likely included into mysource.c with `#include "mysource.h"`.)

Comment: if I have multiple shared library, like -lpcap, -levent, and I only want to statically link libevent but dynamically link libpcap, is it possible or not? thanks!

Comment: Then do not specify `-static` option, but pass `libevent.a` to the linker (like in the first command) and add `-lpcap`.

Comment: I tried `gcc  -o relay -static mysource.c mysource.h /usr/local/lib/libevent.a -lpcap`, but I got errors: like `/home/wgong/Downloads/package/libevent-1.4.14b-stable/event.c:150: undefined reference to clock_gettime`. why?

Comment: thanks, it is ok with `-lrt`, can you explain a bit about `-lrt`? thanks!

Comment: It tells linker to use `librt` library. Well, I guess that libevent.so dynamically links againts librt.so (its functions use functions from librt), and it's handled by loader when we link libevent dynamically. But when we link libevent statically we need to resolve all calls from libevent at the link time.

Answer (score 1):

From the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options):

> **`-static`**
>
> On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking with the shared libraries. On other systems, this option has no effect.